How do I start building on the space platform?
I just launched my first few rockets. I built a space platform and launch some rockets with the building materials for the initial buildings there.
I was able to build foundations on the platform, but if I try to build anything else it only creates a ghost building. I have the required building materials for the asteroid collecter and the other buildings that are initially unlocked.
How do I actually start building stuff in space? What am I missing? What are the first steps to build a space platform?

The buildings must be fabricated on Nauvis.
When you place a ghost on the platform, it will request a "rocket stack" of that building from Nauvis and that stack will be sent with a rocket.
When it arrives, the platform will place it.

Just to add, you can also manually load a rocket with buildings and send it at the launch pad.

It might be worth noting that silos can now connect to the logistic system (toggle in the silo UI), so robots can deliver the buildings to the silo

Buildings does not need to be fabricated on Nauvis, that statement is misleading. Having an assembling machine on the space platform is perfectly okay.


I have the required building materials for the asteroid collecter and the other buildings that are initially unlocked.

Just having the required building materials for e.g. Asteroid Collector is not enough, you need to have the actual Asteroid Collector itself on the space platform to build it.

There are a few ways you can get the buildings there:

Manually insert the required items into the Rocket inventory. Manually click "Deliver cargo" if needed. (If a platform is requesting all the inventory items then the rocket may launch automatically when full)
Deliver assembling machine(s) and inserters and produce the appropriate building on the space platform.

More automated ways of getting the required buildings to the space platform include:

Activate "Automatic requests from space platforms" in your Rocket Silo and logistic robots can deliver what's being requested.
Connect Rocket Silo to circuit network and use circuit conditions to insert requested buildings.

